# Wooccomerce Variable product issue

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing some issue woocommerce variable product. I have to describe in screenshot Please check attachment image

problem is "every time i click on the drop-down instead of selecting pack size i click anywhere outside of the drop-down getting Undefine word appearing

Website URL is:http://www.worldmatrix.co.in/empire/product/ram-bandhu-chilli-powder/

PLEASE HELP ME HOW CAN I SOLVE THE ISSUE

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 529 in the source code: this code where you want to write out availability, but only if it’s not empty:

`if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){`

Do this instead:

`if('' !== $('input.variation_id').val() || 0 !== $('input.variation_id').val()) {`

Because the value is `0` when it’s nothing, not an empty string.

Comment: Hi Vincent Orback thanks for your help Which file need to edit

Comment: I don’t know, maybe you can search your files for the function?